# Get all checked checkbox values to servlet from dynamically generated JSP table?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, parameters

I'm displaying the results of my query from `Table A` in my results.jsp as goes:

```
<form action="InsertToTableB" method="post">
       <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="user" items="${resultData}">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="<c:out value='${user.userID }' />"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.fName }"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.lName }"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.email }"/></td>    
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>    
        </table>
   <button type="submit" value="Submit">Insert to Table B</button>
   <button type="submit" value="Submit">Delete from Table A</button>
</form>
```

And this `form` is being passed into my `InsertToTableB` servlet.

How do I get ONLY the selected values from the generated table `<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="<c:out value='${user.userID }' />"/>`and
how do I know which button (`Insert to Table B` or `Delete from Table A`) has been pressed?

I've only worked with `<input type="text">` and getting the value into the servlet using `.getParameter('name')` and those are `Strings`.

Is it the same for `checkbox` input type?

Can I have 2 or more submit buttons in a form each with a different function?

A picture of my table with sample data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change `name='selected'` to `checked='checked'`

so change

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="<c:out value='${user.userID }' />"/>
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="<c:out value='${user.userID }' />"/>
```

To get all the checked `checkbox`,you can use `jQuery` like below:

```
var checkedEles = $("input:checkbox:checked");
```

Comment: How do I receive the checked values in my controller servlet?  Is it `request.getParameter("checked")` as well?

Comment: @JamesMcTyre You need to get all the checked values via `javascript` and pass them to the server side,you can not get client element directly in server side.

Comment: Thank you for your help.